# Spring Keycloak Adapter loads Open-ID configuration for every single request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a Spring project with Keycloak adapter configured and noticed that it loads openid-configuration for **every request**. Is there any mechanism to cache this configuration, or, why is this happening?

Could not understand this behavior and Keycloak Docs say nothing about this. As I saw the source code, It resolves this configuration when KeycloakDeployment object is created, so every time a request comes a new KeycloakDeployment object is created (see: [Keycloak adapter source](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/f14f92ab0b7f98b5dc18ba20c33dbcc117f04e52/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/KeycloakDeployment.java#L190))

This is the log:

```
2020-06-25 08:31:36.103  INFO 1 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Loaded URLs from https://mykeyloak.com/auth/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Here is my Keycloak adapter configuration:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private KeycloakProperties keycloakProperties;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public AdapterConfig adapterConfig() {
        AdapterConfig adapterConfig = new AdapterConfig();
        adapterConfig.setRealm(keycloakProperties.getRealm());
        adapterConfig.setResource(keycloakProperties.getResource());
        adapterConfig.setAuthServerUrl(keycloakProperties.getAuthServerUrl());
        adapterConfig.setSslRequired(keycloakProperties.getSslRequired());
        adapterConfig.setBearerOnly(keycloakProperties.getBearerOnly());
        adapterConfig.setCredentials(keycloakProperties.getCredentials());
        adapterConfig.setCors(keycloakProperties.getEnableCors());
        adapterConfig.setUseResourceRoleMappings(keycloakProperties.getUseResourceRoleMappings());
        return adapterConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver(AdapterConfig adapterConfig) {
        return new KeycloakConfigResolver() {
            @Override
            public KeycloakDeployment resolve(HttpFacade.Request request) {
                return KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setKeycloakProperties(KeycloakProperties keycloakProperties) {
        this.keycloakProperties = keycloakProperties;
    }
}
```

Keycloak properties:

```
keycloak.realm=myrealm
keycloak.resource=myclient
keycloak.auth-server-url=https://mykeycloak.com/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.credentials={}
keycloak.enable-cors=true
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to register KeycloakDeployment bean and return that from KeycloakConfigResolver resolve method.

```
@Bean
public KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment(AdapterConfig adapterConfig) {
    return KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig);
}

@Bean
public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver(KeycloakDeployment keycloakDeployment) {
    return request -> keycloakDeployment;
}
```